# Plotting different area objects in OSMnx

Tags: python, osmnx

I am wondering if it is possible to plot area objects from OSM through OSMnx.

It seems to me, that there is an easy way only to plot buildings. But I would like to be able to plot e.g. rivers, but can't find a place to specify this.

I was hoping for a similar mechanism to plotting different way objects (e.g. power lines) through `infrastructure` parameter in `graph_from_bbox` function.
Is there something like that but for areas?

What I did already is to try a minimal example:

```
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)
point = (50.045199, 19.939229)
dist = 300
north, south, east, west = ox.bbox_from_point(point, distance=dist)

# power lines around southern california
G = ox.graph_from_bbox(north=north, south=south, east=east, west=west,
                       retain_all=True, truncate_by_edge=True, simplify=False, 
                       network_type='none', infrastructure='way["power"~"line"]')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(ox.project_graph(G))
```

Next I tried to alter the `way["power"~"line"]` for other types of things, including areas, but it returned an error. But I did not find any other obvious way to request area objects than this parameter.

Comment: Is this question only about plotting? That is, have you successfully used OSMnx to download the data of interest and now just want to plot it? If so, please post your code so far.

Comment: Yes, the only thing I want to do is to get some elements from the OSM (e.g. roads and rivers) into a plot and then save it to work with it in a graphics editor. I haven't tried downloading the data itself.

I have never used OSM API or any geo-data software, so I only modified the expamples you kindly provided with osmnx (which are awesome, just as the package, thanks for that!).
So if there is a way around it (getting the data alone and then plotting it separately), it would be great if you could point me to some examples of how to do it.